# Failing negative lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I tried this regex `^([^i]|i(?!s OK))+\.$` on the 2 lines below.

```
1. /tmp/tmp.oW75zGUh4S ... is O.

2. /tmp/tmp.oW75zGUh4S ... is OK.
```

I would expect this regex to match the first one but not the second.  Yet it matchs none.  Why?

If I use the positive lookahead `^([^i]|i(?=s OK))+\.$` then it matchs the second but not first and that is the expected behavior.

Comment: What's the rule for matching ?

Comment: Works here. But it looks more like you'd want `^.*(?<!is OK.)$`, at least, I think it's more readable and moreover easier on the backtraces.

Comment: Example: https://regex101.com/r/vA6tY8/1

Comment: (should of source escape the dot, how often do I forget that :) )

Comment: I tried Oracle regexp_like. I tried notepad++ seach,  I tried Javascript.  All support negative lookhead.

Comment: @Wrikken i'm not looking for lookbehind.  it's not supported in javascript.

Comment: @Wrikken it would not work for `sdskjfskdfj is OK dkfjslkdfjlks`

Comment: So, you're saying, solve it without a lookbehind? Pff, inferior implementations :) Here ya go: [`^(.(?!is OK\.$))+$`](https://regex101.com/r/vA6tY8/3);

Comment: Ow, wait, yeah, the non-lookbehind fails at that, back to the drawing board :)

Comment: Well, toolfail again: https://regex101.com/r/vA6tY8/4 (with negative lookbehind) works, no matter wat regex101 states there. https://regex101.com/r/vA6tY8/5 works with just a lookahead. I don't care what regex101 says, I've tested them :)

Comment: @Wrikken, the dot is supposed to go *after* the lookahead, not before-- i.e., `^((?!is OK\.$).)+$`.  To see why, try matching a line consisting of just `is OK.`, which should fail.  Your regex [matches](https://regex101.com/r/vA6tY8/6) it, because it consumes the `i` before the lookahead sees it.  Also, your [lookbehind regex](https://regex101.com/r/vA6tY8/4) didn't work because you forgot to add the `g` flag.  None of your regexes were even *trying* match anything after the first line.

Answer (score 0):

After testing on regex101.com, I found that a `\n` was missing.  The correct regex is `^([^i\n]|i(?!s OK))+$`.

Thanks Wrikken.

**Update**: Just to explain why the `\n` is missing.  The `^( ... )+$` is greedy which means that it will eat up all the characters it can until it can't and the `[^i]` will eat any one character that is not an `i` so even an end-of-line character. Also, I was wrongly assuming that since `$` meant the match has to end with a end-of-line, it was impossible for the match to cross the end-of-line boundry the same way it is possible to prevent the `.` to cross the end-of-line boundry by setting the right flag. The `$` can mean the end of the whole string but I had used a flag to prevent this.